# cURL PHP Getting value of JSON

Tags: php, json, curl

Response:

```
{
    "error":null,
    "value1":"STRING",
    "valuelist":{
       valueurl:{ 
           "status":STATUS_TEXT,
        },
      }
    }
```

cURL:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $response);

            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);

            $content = curl_exec ($ch);

            curl_close ($ch);

            return $content;
```

now I have json_decoded it, I can't get value of "status".

echo $foo->value1; works fine.

echo $foo->status; isn't right. How would I get that value?

Comment: `$foo-> valuelist->valueurl->status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of status should be access like below:

`$foo->valuelist->valueurl->status`

Answer (score 0):

When sometimes you don't know where is certain property or index you can always maka a var_dum() de variable, example:

```
var_dump(json_decode($content));
```

So you can see the tree structure:

```
$foo->valuelist->valueurl->status
```